# Iterate and concat using XPath Expression

Tags: java, xpath

I have the following xml file:

```
<author>
  <firstname>Akhilesh</firstname>
  <lastname>Singh</lastname>
</author>
<author>
  <firstname>Prassana</firstname>
  <lastname>Nagaraj</lastname>
</author>
```

And I am using the following `JXPath` expression,

```
concat(author/firstName," ",author/lastName)
```

To get the value `Akhilesh Singh ,Prassana Nagaraj` but 
I am getting only `Akhilesh Singh`.

My requirement is that I should get the value of both author by executing only one `JXPath` expression.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a one-liner XPath 2.0 solution. :)

Answer (score 7):

**XPath 2.0 solution**:

```
/*/author/concat(firstname, ' ', lastname, following-sibling::author/string(', '))
```

Comment: Yes, adding a `', '` only if there is a following sibling `author`. But, Do you think this has better performance than `fn:string-join`?

Comment: @Alejandro: before asking about performance, take care to correct your answer -- the OP wants *comma-delimited*, not *NL-delimited* names. The tricky part here is not to have the comma after the last name.

Comment: @Akhilesh-Kumar-singh: I always test my answers. This expression has been verified to produce the correct result -- with Saxon9.1.07 and AltovaXML. You probably are using an XPath 1.0 engine, not an XPath 2.0 one.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Thanks, I built upon this and made it work in my case.

Answer (score 3):

With XPath 1.0, when an argument type other than node set is expected, the first node in the node set is selected and then apply the type conversion (boolean type conversion is some how different).

So, your expresion (*Note: no capital*):

```
concat(author/firstname," ",author/lastname)
```

It's the same as:

```
concat( string( (author/firstname)[1] ), " ", string( (author/lastname)[1] ) )
```

Depending on the host language you could use:

```
author/firstname|author/lastname
```

This is evaluate to a node set with `firstName` and `lastName` in document order, so then you could iterate over this node set extracting the string value.

In XPath 2.0 you could use:

```
string-join(author/concat(firstname,' ', lastname),' ,')
```

Output:

```
Akhilesh Singh ,Prassana Nagaraj
```

**Note**: Now, with sequence data type and function calls as steps, XPath resembles the functional language it claims to be. Higher Order Functions and partial applycation must  wait to XPath 2.1 ...

**Edit**: Thanks to Dimitre's comments, I've corrected the string separator.

Comment: See my answer for a better XPath 2.0 one-liner. :)

Comment: The XPath 2.0 expression constructs a string that ends with " ,", but the OP doesn't want a trailing comma.

Comment: @Dimitre: But there is no trailing separator with `fn:string-join`, by definition. Also tested in Saxon and Altova.

Comment: OK, I'm somewhat abset-minded today -- you still need to change '[space],' to ',[space]' :)

Comment: "|" gives the output in mismatch format and other expressions are not working

Comment: @Akhilesh Kumar singh: Did you read the explanation? Also, did you take notice wich expressions are XPath 1.0 and wich ones are XPath 2.0? Also, when someone post an "Output" in answer, it means that it has been tested. I guess you have no access to XPath 2.0 (rare, did you try Saxon?), so you only have the union expression that it gets evaluete to a node set (not a string like your concat). Take care in casting this result so you don't get a mismatch format.

Answer (score 0):

concat() will return single string. If you want both results then you need to iterate over "author" element and do "`concat(firstName," ",lastName)`"